# New field to SQL and PHP

Tags: php, sql, content-management-system, field

So I wanted to create a small cms I mean it's not even a CMS it's like a catalog for my needs and I found something on internet and changed few things.

But I need 2 more fields, but I use the same pattern to add them and I won't.

Here is the code:

http://pastebin.com/kfkFtUDd

I kno guys that this is the worst code you ever saw but it's only for local use!!

Almost forgot here is the connection and "admin" check.

```
  <?php

      include_once('_class/cms.php');
      $obj = new simpleCMS();

      $obj->host = 'localhost';
      $obj->username = 'root';
      $obj->password = '';
      $obj->table = 'custom_cms';
      $obj->connect();

      if ( $_POST )
        $obj->write($_POST);

      echo ( isset($_GET['admin']) && $_GET['admin'] == 1 ) ? $obj->display_admin() : $obj->display_public();


    ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the write method in simpleCMS look like? And what does the database schema look like?

Comment: php 5.5 has great features, if u wanna use those switch over mysqli rather than mysql driver

Comment: From the code you can see how the table looks.

It forms a testDB with:
title   VARCHAR(150),
pic     VARCHAR(150),
created VARCHAR(100)

I am not good at all in php na sql. I do front-end. So sorry!

Comment: @ajay23romu I know you are probably right... It much better but I don't know either and I am stuck with half working code just have to figure out how to add an input.

Comment: so you want a function to insert ? or what exactly ? if you specify more clearly i would be able to help more

Comment: I have 2 fields now (pic and title) but I want to more field fol and desc. So I would have 4 field that would post in DB.

The DB looks like this
http://i.imgur.com/cMtY3Yh.png

Simply put it I want 2 more variables for PHP and SQL!

Comment: Did you update the database after you added the 2 new fields? What error messages are you getting? What does your code look like after adding the 2 new fields?

Comment: As of right now your code will create the table if it does not exist, but it will not update the table if you add fields. You would have to add those manually.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, time difference.
Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/P748DRnq

No errors, but there is not DB table...